# Can I take a second marriage without permission of first wife?

Tags: sharia, nikah, sunni

My name is Md Ibran Khan and I am from Varansi. I want to marry a second woman but my first (current) wife is not giving permission; I want to remain married to her as well.

Will nikah with the second wife be legal or illegal according to Islam? I am capable of taking responsibility for both of them.